# Trouble to only move files and not directories

Tags: python, file, move, shutil

Trying to move files from logfile_directory to tmp_directory in blocks of 7 using random.sample. 
If there are less than 7 files in the folder it will just move the remainder of the files. However when I try and move less that 7 files I get an error as the tmp_folder is trying to copy into itself.

Tried using glob.glob command but can't get that to work either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong to just move the files and not folder. Any help would be appreciated.

Running the same code on a different machine and getting the below message where as before the error message was related to copying the tmp_folder into itself. Nothing special about this file it's creating the error on so don't know why I'm now getting this.

Message=[WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\securelog_test\bdlog.txt'
  Source=C:\Users\jarra\source\repos\archive_test\archive_test.py
  StackTrace:
  File "\archive_test.py", line 72, in 
    shutil.move(path, tmp_folder)

```py
logfile_directory = 'c:\\securelog_test\\'
archive_folder = 'c:\\securelog_archive\\'
workfiles_folder = 'c:\\securelog_workfiles\\'
tmp_folder = 'c:\\securelog_test\\temp\\'
completed_folder = 'c:\\securelog_test\\completed\\'

#count how many files are in the log file folder
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(logfile_directory) if isfile(join(logfile_directory, f))]
print('-----------------')
print (len(onlyfiles))

if len(onlyfiles) > 7:
    #move 7 random files to the temp folder for archiving
    files = os.listdir(logfile_directory)
    for fileName in random.sample(files, min(len(files), 8)):
        path = os.path.join(logfile_directory, fileName)
        shutil.move(path, tmp_folder)
else:
    #if there are less than 7 files move them
    #for file in glob.glob(logfile_directory):
    #    shutil.move(file, tmp_folder)
    for fileName in os.listdir(logfile_directory):
        path = os.path.join(logfile_directory, fileName)
        shutil.move(path, tmp_folder)
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the full error message.

Comment: also post the real values of the paths

Comment: have updated the code and added the error message, although this time I'm running this on a different computer and getting a different error than before..

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that file existed in the destination folder and couldn't write over it. Not sure why so will look into that eventually.
In order to make my life a bit easier I put the temp and completed folders into their own root folders like below and this seems to work with out any issues. Feel this is cheating a bit and would love to try and figure this out but I need to move onto other elements of the program.

```py
logfile_directory = 'c:\\securelog\\securelog_test\\'
archive_folder = 'c:\\securelog\\securelog_archive\\'
workfiles_folder = 'c:\\securelog\\securelog_workfiles\\'
tmp_folder = 'c:\\securelog\\temp\\'
completed_folder = 'c:\\securelog\\completed\\'
```

Answer (score -2):

check the os current directory path try to print it for each iteration you get where its getting wrong.